# Socket.io latency issue

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io, network-programming

I have created walkies/talkies , where user can communicate in one direction. the audio bytes are broadcasted at real time.

I am facing the issue of network latency. In local network it is working fine, but on live network it goes down.

Following is the information related to it. Please suggest the right way to optimize latency.

Following is the code which is broad casting the bytes:

```
socket.on('talk', function (data) {
    io.emit('listen', data);  
});
```

> **Samples rate per second : 44100 Hz**
>
> **Buffer size: 1024**

At mobile side I have following speed:

> **0.49 Mbps Download**
>
> **0.88 Mbps Upload**

My net speed is as follow, this is the server, where I hosted my socket.io nodejs service, from where I connect the socket from outside network:

[image]

Comment: *Network* latency is something you cannot influence (unless you change your provider, that is). *Application* latency is in your hands (meaning how fast your app takes to encode / decode the sound data). You mention a sample rate of 44100Hz which seems way to high for voice, Reducing it would also reduce the amount of data you send. Increasing buffer size is another option, so your app can work on longer chunks of data per cycle.

Comment: Are you compressing your audio data or just raw samples? how many channels are you encoding (IE: mono or stereo)? what is your sample depth (IE: 16 bit)?

Comment: It is stereo and not compressing, it is raw samples.

Answer (score 0):

*Network latency* is something you cannot influence (unless you change your ISP that is). But *Application latency* is in your hands (meaning how fast your app takes to encode / decode the sound data).

- You mention a sample rate of 44100Hz which seems way too high for voice. Reducing it would also reduce the amount of data you send.
- Increasing buffer size (caching) is another option, so your app can work on longer chunks of data per cycle. This *will* increase latency, but will provide with overall more stable communication
- You may consider switching over from TCP to UDP transport-layer protocol, ridding of ACK packets and hence increasing throughput. If you intend for your application to be used as a real-time voice communication tool, losing on some voice packets (an *inevitable* part of packet-switching networks such as the Internet, compared to the traditional circuit-switched landline networks), and re-capturing them after isn't useful as the conversation moves on
- Speaking of the evitable or inevitable losses, you may consider compressing your audio **without losing quality (lossless)**. Example formats are: FLAC, ALAC and WAV. The lossy (with quality loss) formats (such as MP3) do it even 10-100 times better, with often barely noticeable quality loss, which *may* be a feasible option (think about it, have you ever noticed *any* quality loss on MP3?)
- Finally, check out in general, how to the other popular systems and services (Such as Skype, Discord, Slack or Spotify) solve your problem and perhaps consider applying some of the known techniques they apply.